# I had tried to add gstamount+total but its not adding

Tags: javascript, php

```
              var gstper=document.getElementById('gstper').value
              var total=document.getElementById("totalamount").value;
                      var gstamount =  gstper*total/100;
              document.getElementById('gstamount').value= gstamount;
              document.getElementById('gsttotal').value=gstamount+total;
```

this is my source code which was i tried.

[image]

Comment: Please show your HTML, and even better, a working demo.

Comment: <td><input type="number" id="qty" name="qty" size="2" onkeyup="return CalculateTotal();"></td>
                             <td><input type="number" id="rate" name="rate" size="5" onkeyup="return CalculateTotal();"></td>

Comment: No, please edit your question and put that in there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Value1: <input type="text" id="myvalue1" value="">
Value2: <input type="text" id="myvalue2" value="">

<p id = "myText"></p>
<p>Click the button to change the value of the text field.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   v1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("myvalue1").value);
   v2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("myvalue2").value);
   document.getElementById("myText").innerText = v1+v2;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If you are setting the final value in html element like paragraph,heading tag then use ***.innerText*** or ***.innerHTML*** and if you are using another input text box to display then only use ***.value*** attribute with document.getElementById().

Comment: <td><input type="number" id="qty" name="qty" size="2" onkeyup="return CalculateTotal();"></td>
                             <td><input type="number" id="rate" name="rate" size="5" onkeyup="return CalculateTotal();"></td>

Comment: var gstamount =  gstper*total/100;
                  document.getElementById('gstamount').value= gstamount;
                  document.getElementById('gsttotal').value=gstamount+total;

Answer (score 0):

Do you parse your input value? Because your "document.getElementById('gstper').value" return a string, so try with this:

```
let gstper= parseInt(document.getElementById('gstper').value);
let total=parseInt(document.getElementById("totalamount").value);
let gstamount =  gstper*total/100;

document.getElementById('gstamount').value= gstamount;
document.getElementById('gsttotal').value=gstamount+total;
```

2 more things: 
1) you missed a ";" after the first line
2) use "let" instead of var, is safier